# How to convert RequestHeader to custom object in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public CustomObject createCustomObject(final @RequestHeader("userId") Long userId) {
   ...
}
```

Can I write some custom converter or something like that to convert this RequestHeader userId param to User object so my method will be:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public CustomObject createCustomObject(final User user) {
   ...
}
```

Is it possible to do with spring-mvc?

Comment: Have you tried annotation your latter method argument with `@RequestHeader`? Then simply register a converter for `String` to `User` and be done.

Comment: It depends on how `userId` is posted to the server. If your can post the user object as json/xml, you can use `@RequestBody` annotation. The `User` object posted will contain the `userId` and everything else can be empty. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody

Comment: @RKodakandla It should be posted as header not json/xml.

Comment: @M. Deinum not sure how to register converter. Could please provide some tutorial or url? Should I implement org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter interface?

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-conversion.

Comment: @Korest, could you please post example of solution?

Comment: @zendu Sure, added my answer below. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically I implemented it with the suggestion from the comments.
Below is an example:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;

@RestController
public class SimpleController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String greeting(@RequestHeader(name = "userId") User user) {
        return "Hey, " + user.toString();
    }
}

public class User {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    ...
}
```

And then we'll create a converter:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UserFromHeaderConverter implements Converter<String, User> {

    @Override
    public User convert(final String userId) {
        // fetch user from the database etc.
        
        final User user = new User();
        user.setId(userId);
        user.setFirstName("First");
        user.setLastName("Last");

        return user;
    }
}
```

To test it, please execute: `curl --header "userId: 123" localhost:8080/user`

Result would be: `Hey, User{id='123', firstName='First', lastName='Last'}`

Versions:

- `spring-boot:2.0.3`
- `spring-web:5.0.7`

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you,  you want to receive a parameter and convert it to a complex object.

You must define a custom DataBinder-process implementing [PropertyEditorSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditorSupport.html?is-external=true) and register this for a type.

For example, if you want to get a bd user form id create the class:

```
public class UserEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private final UserDAO   userDao;

    public <T> CacheEditor(UserDAO userDao) {

        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
            Long code = Long.parseLong(text);
            setValue(userDao.getById( code));
        } else {
            setValue(null);
        }
    }
...
}
```

and register editor:

```
@Controller
public class MyFormController {
    @Autowire
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {          
        binder.registerCustomEditor(User.class, new UserEditor(userDao));
    }
....
```

More info:

- [spring-framework reference webdatabinder](http://spring-framework%20reference:%20webdatabinder)
- [an example](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-validator-initbinder/)