# Reading JSON Object from @RequestHeader

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am recieving a JSON object which is comes to me as a String from the front end and I want spring-boot to parse it into a Map for me.

I've tried @RequestHeader("header-name") Map header and @RequestHeader Map header but both give me a map of all the headers instead of the one I'm target which contains the JSON.

```java
public ResponseEntity<MyObject> getStuff(@RequestHeader("My-Header") Map myHeaderJSON)
```

I expect the variable myHeaderJSON string to be parsed into a Map by Spring. Is there any way to achieve this? To have spring-boot parse a String into a JSON or Map for me?

Answer (score 3):

if you want a single http request header to be "injected" into your controller method (as an argument) by Spring try it this way:

```
@RequestMapping("/your-path")
public ResponseEntity<MyObject> getStuff(@RequestHeader("My-Header") String jsonValue) {
   //...
}
```

also see here: https://www.viralpatel.net/spring-requestheader-example/

you can also try to implement a custom converter, see here for an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50996349/150623

the way to go would be to use an `ObjectMapper` instance from the Jackson lib to convert the JSON string to a `java.util.Map` object...

could work this way (not tested though):

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JsonToMapConverter implements Converter<String, Map<String,String>> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> convert(final String json) {
        try {
           return objectMapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           //handle exception...
        }
    }
}
```

don't forget to add Jackson to your dependencies, e.g. in Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Any way to avoid using String and go straight to a Map?

Answer (score 2):

No, you will need to de-serialise it yourself.

From the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html):

> If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>`, `MultiValueMap<String, String>`, or `HttpHeaders` then the map is populated with all header names and values.

It will not extract and deserialise json from the map, instead you will need to do something like:

```
public ResponseEntity<MyObject> getStuff(@RequestHeader Map myHeader) { 
    String json = myHeader.get("My-Header");
    MyClass myClass = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);

    ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing it like this!